# Django 1.9 testing timezone.now()

Tags: django, unit-testing, python-3.x, django-models, django-timezone

**TL;DR**: Get only current date and current hour and current minute from `timezone.now()` and not seconds and miliseconds.

Django version: 1.9
Python version: 3.5.1

While testing my app's model, I encountered a strange (to me) error.

I have this model:

```
import datetime

from django.core.urlresolvers   import reverse
from django.utils               import timezone
from django.db                  import models

class Muayene(models.Model):
    ...
    muayene_tarihi = models.DateField(
        default = timezone.now
    )
    ...
```

and this unit test:

```
import datetime

from django.test                    import TestCase
from django.utils                   import timezone

from hasta.models                   import Hasta
from muayene.models                 import Muayene

class MuayeneModelTest(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['muayene_testdata', 'hasta_testdata']

    def setUp(self):
        Hasta.objects.create(ad="foo",soyad="bar",tc_kimlik_no="1234")
    def test_default_muayene_tarihi(self):
        hasta = Hasta.objects.get(ad="foo")
        muayene = Muayene.objects.create(hasta=hasta)
        self.assertEqual(muayene.muayene_tarihi, timezone.now())
```

Output of test:

```
FAIL: test_default_muayene_tarihi (muayene.tests.test_models.MuayeneModelTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/egegunes/Dropbox/Programs/hastatakip/muayene/tests/test_models.py", line 21, in test_default_muayene_tarihi
      self.assertEqual(muayene.muayene_tarihi, timezone.now())
      AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 8, 14, 38, 54, 780069, tzinfo=<UTC>) != datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 8, 14, 38, 54, 780539, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

As you can notice, the problem is difference between outputs of `timezone.now` which called from `models.py` and `timezone.now()` which called form `test_models.py`.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160022/django-1-5-timezone-now) for a workaround. But storing the exact milisecond or second is not my real intent. I want only current date and time (hour and minute). Also I don't want to set `default = datetime.date.today()` or something like that because django gives warnings about using only `timezone.now`.

So my question is, how can I get only and only current date, hour and minute with `timezone.now()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can pass any callable to `default`, just write your own function to do it. For example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

def strip_seconds(dt):
    return dt.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)

def now():
    return strip_seconds(timezone.now())

class Muayene(models.Model):
    # Note that this should be a DateTimeField, not a DateField
    muayene_tarihi = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

So in your tests you can compare the return value of your version of `now()` to what's in the database (or call `strip_seconds()` on any arbitrary datetime).

Note that comparing for equality still isn't entirely robust, since it will be possible to get a test failure if the two calls happen to straddle a minute boundary.

Comment: Well then, am I following recommendation about setting default value to `timezone.now` by using this function and `default=now`?

Comment: @egegunes: The recommendation is to use Django's version of `now()` instead of Python's, since it takes the timezone settings into account. The code I posted does that. There's no recommendation about what callable `default` should point to. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField), for example: "If you need something different, you may want to consider simply using your own callable default."

Comment: Thank you Kevin, it seems to work.